tensorflow.keras.layers.Flatten() throwing INVALID_ARGUMENT error
I have created this computer vision model using tensorflow.keras with grouped convolutions this way:
    n_filters = [8, 16, 32]
    img_dims = (128,572,1)
    layer_dims = calculate_dims(img_dims,conv_filters=n_filters)
    print('Layer dimensions')
    for l in layer_dims:
        print(l)
    last_neurons = layer_dims[-1][0]*layer_dims[-1][1]*layer_dims[-1][2]
    
    model = Sequential()
    
    model.add(tf.keras.Input(shape=(img_dims)))
    
    model.add(layers.Conv2D(n_filters[0], kernel_size=3, padding = "same", activation = "relu"))

    for n in n_filters[1:]:
        model.add(layers.Conv2D(n, kernel_size=3, padding = "same", activation = "relu",groups=2))
        model.add(layers.MaxPool2D(2))    

    model.add(layers.Flatten())
    
    model.add(layers.Dense(64, activation="relu"))
    
    model.add(layers.Dense(8, activation="relu"))

    model.add(layers.Dense(1, activation='relu'))

    return model

This is the model.summary() output
┏━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━┳━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━┳━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━┓
┃ Layer (type)                    ┃ Output Shape           ┃       Param # ┃
┡━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━╇━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━╇━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━┩
│ conv2d (Conv2D)                 │ (None, 128, 572, 8)    │            80 │
├─────────────────────────────────┼────────────────────────┼───────────────┤
│ conv2d_1 (Conv2D)               │ (None, 128, 572, 16)   │           592 │
├─────────────────────────────────┼────────────────────────┼───────────────┤
│ max_pooling2d (MaxPooling2D)    │ (None, 64, 286, 16)    │             0 │
├─────────────────────────────────┼────────────────────────┼───────────────┤
│ conv2d_2 (Conv2D)               │ (None, 64, 286, 32)    │         2,336 │
├─────────────────────────────────┼────────────────────────┼───────────────┤
│ max_pooling2d_1 (MaxPooling2D)  │ (None, 32, 143, 32)    │             0 │
├─────────────────────────────────┼────────────────────────┼───────────────┤
│ flatten (Flatten)               │ (None, 146432)         │             0 │
├─────────────────────────────────┼────────────────────────┼───────────────┤
│ dense (Dense)                   │ (None, 64)             │     9,371,712 │
├─────────────────────────────────┼────────────────────────┼───────────────┤
│ dense_1 (Dense)                 │ (None, 8)              │           520 │
├─────────────────────────────────┼────────────────────────┼───────────────┤
│ dense_2 (Dense)                 │ (None, 1)              │             9 │
└─────────────────────────────────┴────────────────────────┴───────────────┘

Total params: 9,375,249 (35.76 MB)
Trainable params: 9,375,249 (35.76 MB)
Non-trainable params: 0 (0.00 B)
Training this way.
model.compile(optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=1e-3),
                  loss="mean_squared_error",
                  metrics=['root_mean_squared_error', 'mean_absolute_error'], 
             )
model_history = model.fit(
    train_dataset,
    validation_data=val_dataset,
    batch_size=4,
    epochs=2,
    verbose=2
)

I am getting an error on the flatten layer:
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
InvalidArgumentError                      Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[16], line 1
----> 1 model_history = model.fit(
      2     train_dataset,
      3     validation_data=val_dataset,
      4     batch_size=4,
      5     epochs=2,
      6     # callbacks=callbacks,
      7     verbose=2
      8 )
      9 completed = dt.now()

File ~/torch_cuda12_env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/src/utils/traceback_utils.py:122, in filter_traceback.<locals>.error_handler(*args, **kwargs)
    119     filtered_tb = _process_traceback_frames(e.__traceback__)
    120     # To get the full stack trace, call:
    121     # `keras.config.disable_traceback_filtering()`
--> 122     raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
    123 finally:
    124     del filtered_tb

File ~/torch_cuda12_env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/execute.py:53, in quick_execute(op_name, num_outputs, inputs, attrs, ctx, name)
     51 try:
     52   ctx.ensure_initialized()
---> 53   tensors = pywrap_tfe.TFE_Py_Execute(ctx._handle, device_name, op_name,
     54                                       inputs, attrs, num_outputs)
     55 except core._NotOkStatusException as e:
     56   if name is not None:

InvalidArgumentError: Graph execution error:

Detected at node sequential_1/flatten_1/Reshape defined at (most recent call last):
<stack traces unavailable>
only one input size may be -1, not both 0 and 1

Stack trace for op definition: 
File "usr/lib/python3.10/runpy.py", line 196, in _run_module_as_main
File "usr/lib/python3.10/runpy.py", line 86, in _run_code
File "/python3.10/site-packages/ipykernel_launcher.py", line 18, in <module>
File "/python3.10/site-packages/traitlets/config/application.py", line 1075, in launch_instance
File "/python3.10/site-packages/ipykernel/kernelapp.py", line 739, in start
File "/python3.10/site-packages/tornado/platform/asyncio.py", line 205, in start
File "usr/lib/python3.10/asyncio/base_events.py", line 603, in run_forever
File "usr/lib/python3.10/asyncio/base_events.py", line 1909, in _run_once
File "usr/lib/python3.10/asyncio/events.py", line 80, in _run
File "/python3.10/site-packages/ipykernel/kernelbase.py", line 545, in dispatch_queue
File "/python3.10/site-packages/ipykernel/kernelbase.py", line 534, in process_one
File "/python3.10/site-packages/ipykernel/kernelbase.py", line 437, in dispatch_shell
File "/python3.10/site-packages/ipykernel/ipkernel.py", line 362, in execute_request
File "/python3.10/site-packages/ipykernel/kernelbase.py", line 778, in execute_request
File "/python3.10/site-packages/ipykernel/ipkernel.py", line 449, in do_execute
File "/python3.10/site-packages/ipykernel/zmqshell.py", line 549, in run_cell
File "/python3.10/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 3075, in run_cell
File "/python3.10/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 3130, in _run_cell
File "/python3.10/site-packages/IPython/core/async_helpers.py", line 129, in _pseudo_sync_runner
File "/python3.10/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 3334, in run_cell_async
File "/python3.10/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 3517, in run_ast_nodes
File "/python3.10/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 3577, in run_code
File "tmp/ipykernel_97254/668273277.py", line 1, in <module>
File "/python3.10/site-packages/keras/src/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 117, in error_handler
File "/python3.10/site-packages/keras/src/backend/tensorflow/trainer.py", line 329, in fit
File "/python3.10/site-packages/keras/src/backend/tensorflow/trainer.py", line 122, in one_step_on_iterator
File "/python3.10/site-packages/keras/src/backend/tensorflow/trainer.py", line 110, in one_step_on_data
File "/python3.10/site-packages/keras/src/backend/tensorflow/trainer.py", line 57, in train_step
File "/python3.10/site-packages/keras/src/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 117, in error_handler
File "/python3.10/site-packages/keras/src/layers/layer.py", line 826, in __call__
File "/python3.10/site-packages/keras/src/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 117, in error_handler
File "/python3.10/site-packages/keras/src/ops/operation.py", line 48, in __call__
File "/python3.10/site-packages/keras/src/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 156, in error_handler
File "/python3.10/site-packages/keras/src/models/sequential.py", line 206, in call
File "/python3.10/site-packages/keras/src/models/functional.py", line 199, in call
File "/python3.10/site-packages/keras/src/ops/function.py", line 151, in _run_through_graph
File "/python3.10/site-packages/keras/src/models/functional.py", line 583, in call
File "/python3.10/site-packages/keras/src/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 117, in error_handler
File "/python3.10/site-packages/keras/src/layers/layer.py", line 826, in __call__
File "/python3.10/site-packages/keras/src/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 117, in error_handler
File "/python3.10/site-packages/keras/src/ops/operation.py", line 48, in __call__
File "/python3.10/site-packages/keras/src/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 156, in error_handler
File "/python3.10/site-packages/keras/src/layers/reshaping/flatten.py", line 54, in call
File "/python3.10/site-packages/keras/src/ops/numpy.py", line 4527, in reshape
File "/python3.10/site-packages/keras/src/backend/tensorflow/numpy.py", line 1618, in reshape

     [[{{node sequential_1/flatten_1/Reshape}}]]
    tf2xla conversion failed while converting __inference_one_step_on_data_2376[]. Run with TF_DUMP_GRAPH_PREFIX=/path/to/dump/dir and --vmodule=xla_compiler=2 to obtain a dump of the compiled functions.
     [[StatefulPartitionedCall]] [Op:__inference_one_step_on_iterator_2471]

I have tried to read up more about keras layers but nothing points me towards an error in the Flatten layer. I also tried to give the input_shape to the Flatten layer as (32, 143, 32) but even that has not resolved the problem.
Not sure if the library versions have anything to do with this error that I am encountering for the first time. I am using these libraries:

keras==3.2.1
numpy==1.26.4
nvidia-cudnn-cu12==8.9.2.26
tensorflow==2.16.1
torch==2.2.2
torchaudio==2.2.2
torchvision==0.17.2
Im not really using the torch libraries for this model but putting it here in case of interaction with other library versions.


This is a problem with tensorflow v2.16. After downgrading to v2.15 the model is compiling and training properly.
